# A question on the defintion of Markov process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

Included in the defintion of the Markov process is the following

$\text{ for } x \in \mathbb{R}^d,s,t \ge 0, \Gamma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$
$$,
P^x[X_{t+s} \in \Gamma \mid X_s=y]=P^y[X_t \in \Gamma],P^xX_s^{-1}\text{- a.s.} y
$$

Now what is bothering me is that if $X_s$ has a continuous density this conditional probability is not well defined as the set $\{X_s=y\}$ has measure zero for all $y$. But for any nice stochastic process to be markov, it has to satisfy this condition(and some others which I havent written here). How do I resolve this paradox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $P^{}[X_{t+s}\in \Gamma |X_s]$ as $f(X_s)$ for some measurable function $f$. In Markov property LHS is interpreted as  $f(y)$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I was wondering if you have some advise on reading more about the makor and strong markov property in a fashion similar to Brownian Motion and stochastic calculus by Karatazas and Shreve. I apologize if this comment is inappropriate

Comment: Lectures from Markov Processes to Brownian Motion by KL Chung may be on interest to you.

Comment: Thank you very much . I just downloaded it